# Re-Queue a failed job in Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resque

If an exception occurred in processing of a background job then how can i make it in queue again so it automatically get processed.

As in my scenario the background process having external (HTTP) calls so there are chances of network latency, so i would like to make it re-queue in case of network failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A gem called `resque-retry` can handle this.

"provides retry, delay and exponential backoff support for resque jobs"

https://github.com/lantins/resque-retry

If you need a ruby 1.9 compatible version have a look through the forks, someone has been working on making it function correctly.